# How to apply reduceByKey in Spark on some of fields in a Class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here's the scenario, I have a JavaBean Class as below:

```
class JB implements Serializable {
  private String field_a;
  private String field_b;
  private String field_c;

  // getter & setter
  ...

  // toString
  ...
}
```

I've got a RDD in Spark whose elements are instances of JB Class. What I intend to do is to apply `reduceByKey` on this RDD, in which, (field_a, field_b) being the key is required.

Is there a decent way to achieve that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to clarify your need better. As of now... its kind of unanswerable.

Comment: What I want is to do group operation on (field_a, field_b), and then apply a function on different field_c. I just don't know how to achieve that via Spark's `reduceByKey` on this Class. @SarveshKumarSingh

Comment: Now... it makes sense.

Comment: So, any solution will be appreciated! Thx in advance! @SarveshKumarSingh

Answer (score 0):

`reduceByKey` takes a function that aggregates two elements of the type of the `RDD<T>` and produces one: `reduceByKey: (T,T) => T`. Note that this function should be associative. That is: `(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)`

In this specific case, that function should look like: `f(JB,JB) => JB`

```
rdd.reduceByKey(
  new Function2<JB, JB, JB>() {
    public JB call(JB a, JB b) { 
       JB res = add(a,b)
       return res;
    }
});
```

Comment: Currently, rdd has no `reduceByKey` method, because the element in it is not of `Tuple2` type. But thanks anyway, could you enhance your code a bit?

Comment: @Judking just map your original rdd to the required form. I believe this is answering the question being asked. If you have another question, I'd suggest you post a new one.

Comment: My question contains the part that how to do the mapping procedure. @maasg

Comment: Use [JavaRDD.mapToPair](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#mapToPair(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction))

Answer (score 0):

```
 //lets say we have a RDD<JB>, identified by jbRdd

 RDD<JB> newRdd = jbRdd
     .groupBy( new Function1<JB, String>() {
         public String call( JB jb ) {
             // return a string formed by both keys
             return "$$fieldA$" + jb.getFieldA() + "$$fieldB" + jb.getFieldB();
         }
     } )
     .reduce( new Function2<JB, JB, JB>() {
         public JB call( JB jb1, JB jb2 ) {
             // create your newJb using jb1 and jb2 however you like.
             return newJb;
         }    
     } );
```

Comment: Tried my best to convert scala to Java. If there are any errors... please point them out.